# displaying a vector of deques in columns

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, deque

I'm trying to display a vector of deques (`std::vector<std::deque<int>> v`) like this

```
v.at(0).at(0) v.at(1).at(0) v.at(2).at(0) v.at(3).at(0)
v.at(0).at(1) v.at(1).at(1) v.at(2).at(1) v.at(3).at(1)
v.at(0).at(2) v.at(1).at(2) v.at(2).at(2) v.at(3).at(2)
              v.at(1).at(3)               v.at(3).at(3)
                                          v.at(3).at(4)
```

The first part of the vector is fixed at 7, the size of the actual columns are dynamic however depending on what the user chooses to do.

I was attempting something like

```
int row = 0;
int column;

for (column = 0; column < v.at(row).size(); column++){
      cout << "v["<< row <<"]["<< column << "]" << v.at(row).at(column) << "\t";
  while (row < v.size()){
    cout << endl;      
    row++;
  }
}
```

I'm getting errors like

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector
make: *** [Pile.h] Abort trap: 6
```

Having one of those blah brain days. Can someone help me print this out the way I want it?

Comment: The error [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) is thrown when you pass an argument to `at` that isn't a valid index. If you look at your `for` loop, on the second iteration `row` is necessarily equal or greater than `v.size()`. The condition tries to call `v.at(row)` which must then fail. The reasoning behind your code is unclear to me.

Comment: You do `++row` in the `while` loop, thus you have (I call it) a wild, independent variable denoting the number of dimensions in a vector.  Then you use this wild, unchecked variable here: `v.at(row).`.  You should strive from not doing this, and always use `size()` to determine the number of elements.

Comment: My code doesn't work, my reasoning is flawed, I'm having a hard time this morning. I'm trying to find out how to get the data in the vector in the output I have shown above, do you have any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: The main piece of advice I'd give is to write the two loops straight forwardly and then either output the entry at that cell, or blank if there are not that many entries in the corresponding column. You will need to either take the maximum of the number of items in any columns, or iterate until none of the columns output an item.

Comment: That loop should look something like this: `for (column = 0; row < v.size() && column < v.at(row).size(); column++)`  -- Your `row` variable goes off because of the internal `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows one of approaches to the task.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::deque<int>> v =
    {
        { 0, 1, 2 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3 },
        { 0, 1, 2 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
    };

    size_t n = std::max_element( v.begin(), v.end(),
                                 []( const auto &x, const auto &y )
                                 {
                                    return x.size() < y.size();
                                 } )->size();

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < v.size(); j++ )
        {
            std::cout << std::setw( 4 );
            if ( i < v[j].size() )
            {
                std::cout << v[j][i];
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "";
            }
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
   0   0   0   0
   1   1   1   1
   2   2   2   2
       3       3
               4
```

Comment: my compiler doesn't like the closure/lambda you're using, "error: 'auto' not allowed in lambda parameter
                                     []( const auto &x, const auto &y )" are you using something other than c++11? What am I not using?

Comment: @BrendanJackson When you need explicitly to write const std::deque<int> &x, const std::deque<int> &y

Comment: That's it, you're my hero!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest to get the max queue size

```
std::size_t  maxQ { 0U };

for ( auto const & q : v )
    maxQ = std::max(maxQ, q.size());
```

Now you can write a loop over `(0U, maxQ(` (the loop of lines) writing elements when available and space otherwise.

```
for ( auto i = 0U ; i < maxQ ; ++i )
 {
   for ( auto j = 0U ; j < v.size() ; ++j )
      if ( i < v[j].size() )
         ; // print v[j][i]
      else
         ; // print space

   std::cout << std::endl; // endl of line
 }
```

I leave to you cells printing details

Comment: I suspect you haven't actually tried your solution. You would need to print by-column. The complexity of this solution would then lie in the part you omitted.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - Well... I've forgotten the end of line (thanks); added. It seems to me that the OP has difficult managing the indexes (row and columns). This answer (I hope) should explain how to do it.

Comment: its almost perfect, everything gets pulled left though, is there something I should be doing with iomanip or another library possibly?

Comment: @BrendanJackson - sorry but I don't understand what do you want to do with `iomanip` or other libraries